# How to use Ajax in magento 2 custom module

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, jquery, magento-2.0.7

I am working on one custom module and i need product load when any ID is clicked. Loading is handle by ajax. I am not aware of ajax in Magento 2. Can anybody give me small demo of ajax in Magento 2

**Controller file**

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;



class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param NewsFactory $modelNewsFactory
 */



public function __construct(
        Context                                             $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory    $resultJsonFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory            = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


   public function execute()
    {
        /*Put below your code*/
        // $id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id', false);
        $responseData = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultJson = $this->resultPageFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($responseData);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

**router file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="modulename" frontName="modulename">
            <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Template file**

```
<script>
    require(
        ['jquery','example'],
        function($,example){

        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>';
        example.exampleData(ajaxurl);

    }); 
</script>
```

**Js file**

```
define([
        'jquery',
        ],
    function($,example){

return {
    exampleData:function(ajaxurl){
    $(document).on('click','.example-list',function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var id=$(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url:ajaxurl,
                type:'POST',
                showLoader: true,
                dataType:'json',
                data: {id:id},                                      
                success:function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

});
```

The above code is not working. It's showing error.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-make-a-simple-ajax-call-in-magento-2-1-0 or http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130372/how-do-i-create-my-own-action-in-controller-to-call-url-from-ajax-in-magento-2-0